# Is it possible to get the ADMX files for Office without manually running the exe?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am currently trying to provision a Virtualized AD Domain, but encountered a bit of a weirdness

The clients for that domain will have Office 2021 installed, so I am trying to automate pull of the Administrative Templates (ADMX/ADML) for Office (to install them into Central Store).

I can extract and install them manually, but I can't find how to do it automatically, it seems to only be pushed as an EXE, and I can't find a way to get them officially in a non-executable format

Answer (score 0):

I had the idea of running the executable on the command line with `\?` to try to display some kind of help message

```
& .\admintemplates_x86_5372-1000_en-us.exe /?
```

And it popped up this menu (transcribed) :

```
Usage:
/extract:path, extracts the content of the package to the path folder
/log[:to log file], enables verbose logging for the update
installation
/lang:lcid, sets the user interface to the specified locale when multiple
locales are available within the package
/quiet, runs the package in silent mode
/passive, runs the update without any interaction from the user
/norestart, prevents prompting of user when reboot of machine is
needed
/forcerestart, forced restart of machine once update is complete
/?, shows this help message
```

Doing (in PowerShell)

```
& .\admintemplates_x86_5372-1000_en-us.exe /extract:$pwd/admx /passive /quiet
```

Will extract the files automatically to `.\admx`